# How to read a .mat file using liboctave and access struct elements?

Tags: c++, octave

I am trying to convert the following Matlab/Octave program to C++/liboctave.

```matlab
% s is struct with 3 real vector fields and 2 scalars.
s = load("L_octave.mat");
Lpos = sparse(s.i, s.j, s.v, s.m, s.n);
[~,dpos] = eigs(Lpos, 51, 'sm');
disp(diag(dpos));
```

I've tried to follow the `standalonebuiltin.cc` example from https://docs.octave.org/latest/Standalone-Programs.html:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/interpreter.h>
#include <octave/builtin-defun-decls.h>
int main()
{
    octave::interpreter interpreter;
    interpreter.execute();

    octave_value_list in;
    in(0) = "L_octave.mat";    
    octave_value_list out = Fload(interpreter, in);

    
    // if uncommented fails with terminate called after throwing an instance 'octave::execution_exception' what():  octave_base_value::map_value(): wrong type argument '<unknown type>'
    // octave_scalar_map arg0 = out(0).scalar_map_value();
    // octave_value i = arg0.contents("i");
    
    return 0;
}
```

This example compiles and runs, but I cannot understand so far how to access the struct fields (or adjust the `.mat` reading code) and to build the sparse matrix.

The documentation on Octave's C++ interface  / liboctave seems a little sparse (I tried https://docs.octave.org/latest/Structures-in-Oct_002dFiles.html, but can't figure out how to access the struct's field)

Grateful for any help!

---

**UPD:**

My current version is:

```cpp
/*
   Attr Name         Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====         ====                     =====  =====
        i      3188406x1                   25507248  double
        j      3188406x1                   25507248  double
        m            1x1                          8  double
        n            1x1                          8  double
        v      3188406x1                   25507248  double
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/interpreter.h>
#include <octave/builtin-defun-decls.h>
int main()
{
    octave_value_list in;
    in(0) = "L_octave.mat";
    octave::interpreter interpreter;
    interpreter.execute ();

    octave_value_list out = Fload (interpreter, in, 1);
    octave_scalar_map arg0 = out(0).scalar_map_value ();
    ColumnVector i = arg0.contents("i").vector_value();
    ColumnVector j = arg0.contents("j").vector_value();
    ColumnVector v = arg0.contents("v").vector_value();
    octave_value m = arg0.contents("m").scalar_value();
    octave_value n = arg0.contents("n").scalar_value();

    // how to construct a sparse matrix and call eigs same as in this octave code? likely need some type casts?
    // Lpos = sparse(s.i, s.j, s.v, s.m, s.n);
    // [eigvec,eigval] = eigs(Lpos, 51,'sm');
    //SparseMatrix (const Array<double>& a, const idx_vector& r, const idx_vector& c, octave_idx_type nr = -1, octave_idx_type nc = -1, bool sum_terms = true, octave_idx_type nzm = -1)
    //SparseMatrix Lpos(v, i, j, m, n);
    //octave_value_list eigvec_and_eigval = Feigs(Lpos, 51, "sm");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `Fload` has this signature:

```
extern OCTINTERP_API octave_value_list
Fload (octave::interpreter&,
       const octave_value_list& = octave_value_list (), 
       int = 0);
```

The last parameter is the number of the function output arguments that is by default `0`. Here you need one output argument so you should set it to `1`:

```
    octave_value_list out = Fload(interpreter, in, 1);
```

Setting the number of outputs to `0` is same as calling the `load` function in Octave without requesting the output:

```
load L_octave.mat
```

In that case all variables in the .mat file are assigned to the corresponding variables in the current workspace of the interpreter.

**UPDATE**:
Here is the complete example that worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/interpreter.h>
#include <octave/builtin-defun-decls.h>
int main()
{
    octave_value_list in;
    in(0) = "L_octave.mat";
    octave::interpreter interpreter;
    interpreter.execute ();

    octave_value_list out = Fload (interpreter, in, 1);
    octave_scalar_map arg0 = out(0).scalar_map_value ();

    octave_value i = arg0.contents("i");
    octave_value j = arg0.contents("j");
    octave_value v = arg0.contents("v");
    octave_value m = arg0.contents("m");
    octave_value n = arg0.contents("n");
    auto Lpos = octave::Fsparse(ovl(i, j, v, m, n), 1)(0);
    auto dpos = octave::Ffeval(interpreter, ovl("eigs", Lpos, 51.0, "sm"), 2)(1);
    octave::Fdisp(octave::Fdiag(dpos, 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It almost works and I can maybe factor out the remaining problems into new questions. With your suggestions, the updated code in the OP compiles and runs. But as I don't know yet how to construct a SparseMatrix for now (I would need to read up on `octave_idx_type`, `Array` etc), could you please check if I'm using `vector_value()` and `scalar_value()` correctly and assigning them in correct types? (`m` and `n` are in fact ints but got dumped as 1x1 double values) I added the `whos` output for reference?

Comment: It also seems that `Feigs` is non-existent (but `Feig` does exist)...

Comment: Or maybe does `Feig` dispatch to `eigs` under the hood if the input is sparse?

Comment: @VadimKantorov I updated the answer providing the complete example. `eigs` isn't a built-in function but is a .m function that should be called by `feval`.

Comment: Thank you! Marked as accepted! Haha, the point of all this exercice was to debug `eigs` using gdb :) I'll see if I can step into `feval`.  I think, `eigs` is somehow still not a .m function, as it's coded in C++ in `libinterp`: https://github.com/gnu-octave/octave/blob/default/libinterp/corefcn/__eigs__.cc which is core part of octave

Comment: If you think there are any bugs you can submit the issues to the [Octave bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave). Where there are persons that know how to debug. Use `which eigs` to find where the function is placed. You can run the code in Octave and use gdb to debug Octave itself.

Comment: Somehow, we are both correct. `eigs.m` calls C++'s `__eigs__` under the hood after some input validation: https://github.com/gnu-octave/octave/blob/default/scripts/sparse/eigs.m#L338, but `F__eigs__` seems not existent (although I'll double-check). Thanks for suggestions on asking out debugging help in the Octave bug tracker! If there exists a debug version or debug symbols are available, this should be possible indeed!

Comment: `DEFMETHOD(__eigs__...` creates the function `F__eigs__`. Possibly __eigs__ calls other functions to do the computations. As explained [here](https://wiki.octave.org/wiki/index.php?title=Debugging_Octave) you can recompile octave with debug symbols.